# Create hash table with dynamically allocated array?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, hashmap

For my assignment I have to create a hash table and I've managed to write most of the hash table until I realized that I declared a static array in my header file. The hash table is suppose to implement a dynamically allocated array and I'm wondering where this array would get created? Would I put it in my header file or do I put it inside my constructor. If I create it in my constructor how will my other member functions access and modify the array since it's in the scope of my constructor. Thank you

```
Item* ptr = new Item[bucketcount];
```

Comment: Don't make it static--make the pointer a normal member variable, and allocate space in your constructor (but for real use, you also want to avoid `new[]` too).

Comment: would the member variable be something like `Item* mem_var;`. Then in my constructor I would do `mem_var = new Item[bucketcount];`? Is this fine? Then I would use `mem_var` in my other member functions such as (add, remove, etc.) to access my array.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much the idea.

Comment: Tyvm. I spent forever trying to figure it out and it was that simple..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't completely understand your question, but if your problem is a "scope" problem, you can solve it by declaring your array as a member of your HashTable class:

HashTable.cpp

```
class HashTable
{
private:
    Item* items;

public:
    HashTable()
    {
        items = new Item[size];
    }

    ~HashTable()
    {
        delete[] items;
    }
};
```

As a member it will be visible from every method of your HashTable class.

Comment: Basically what Jerry said. Thank you for the code example